# Filter array that only contains emails

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to filter an array that only contains emails,

I did this

```
 emails = emails.filter((x)=>(x !== (undefined || null || '')))
```

that delete the empty value, but can accept a value that is not an email.

Comment: What is your criteria to define an email?   @ symbol or?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: @JoshAdams contain @ yest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

```
let re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
emails = emails.filter(e =>e && e.toLowerCase().match(re));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the regular expression found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) you can complete your filter like so:

```js
var emails = [];

emails = emails.filter(e => typeof e == "string" && validEmail(e));

console.log(emails);

function validEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email.toLowerCase());
}
```